# Want to compare a config parameter and replace if value is different using Awk and Sed

Tags: bash, replace, awk, sed

Have a config file with key values

```
key1=1   
key2=2
key5=6
```

Want to replace the value of key5 if it is not 5 with a value of 10

```
awk '
BEGIN{FLAG=0}
/key5=6/{FLAG=1}
END { if (FLAG == 0) {sed -i "s/^key5.*/key5=10/1"
    print "key5 is now 10" } }' test.config
```

Code is on different lines.  Also, ignore beginning and ending double quotes.  Could not do it properly with this editor. 
The sed command is not working, am I escaping it properly?
sed works fine by itself on the command line

Comment: You mean this `sed 's/key5=[^5]/key5=10/' file` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, tried that on my file containing `key5=57` and it didn't work :-)

Comment: `perl -pe  's/key5=(?!5\b)\d+/key5=10/'`

Comment: Your question looks as if you've tried to embed an invocation of `sed` right inside your awk script.  That won't work.  Use one or the other, or feed the output of one to the other through a pipe.  Or perhaps, just use `sed -r 's/key5=([^5][0-9]*|5[0-9]+)/key5=10/' file` ?  Also check the `awk` man page for awk's `sub()` command, and perhaps `gensub()` if you're using gawk.

Comment: @Avinash You should make an answer with `sed 's/key5=[^5]/key5=10/' file` just solve the double quotes as well (second sed -e parameter?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed: if the line starts with `key5=` and it does *not* end with `=5` then replace the value

```
sed '/^key5=/ {/=5$/! s/=.*/=10/}' <<END
key1=1   
key2=2
key5=5
key5=6
END
```

```
key1=1   
key2=2
key5=5
key5=10
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that your config file's key-value pairs are actually each on a separate line, which is what your `awk` command suggests.

It looks like you're trying to call `sed` from *directly within* an `awk` program, which won't work - the only way to call other utilities from `awk` is to use either the `system()` function or a pipeline (`"<cmd>" | getline ...`).

However, this is rarely the right approach; instead, use `awk`'s ability to modify input fields:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="=" } $1=="key5" && $2!=5 { $2 = 10 } { print }' test.config
```

- `BEGIN{ FS=OFS="=" }` tells `awk` to split each input line into fields by `=` (`FS`), and also to separate output fields with `=` (`OFS`).

  - `OFS` applies when using `print` with multiple arguments, and when causing an input line to be rebuilt by assigning to an input field.
- `$1=="key5" && $2!=5` matches a line where the key part is `key5`, and the value part is *not* `5`

  - Assigning `10` to `$2` - the 2nd input field - then causes the input line to be *rebuilt*, resulting in `key5=10`
- `{ print }` simply prints each (possibly modified) input line.